# How to disable error checking in VSCode for net46 framework on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, coreclr

I have ASP.NET Core project which has both **netcoreapp** and **net46** in frameworks section. I can build and run it without any problem on Mac OS X. But when i open it in VSCode it shows tons of errors like this: `Predefined type '...' is not defined or imported [net46]` and everything is red.

Is there any way to fix it without removing net46 from project.json?

Frameworks section of my project.json:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net46": {
    "dependencies": {
      "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0-*"
    }
  },
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "version": "1.0.0-*",
        "type": "platform"
      },
      "System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-*"
    },
    "imports": [
      "dnxcore50"
    ]
  }
}
```